# JQuery: SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have seen the other jquery post about this syntax error. But i really cannot find the error for this.

```
var projects = new Object();

$("#project_"+projectId+" .todo_input").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('disabled') == false){
        id = $(this).attr('id')
        val = $(this).val();
        pos = id.indexOf('_', 6);
        projectId = id.substr(6, pos - 6);
        taskId = id.substr(pos + 1);

        if(projects[projectId] == undefined)
            projects[projectId] = new Object();

        if(projects[projectId][taskId] == undefined)
            projects[projectId][taskId] = val;
    }
});

var today = new Date();


var w = $(document).getUrlParam("week");
var y = $(document).getUrlParam("year");

if(w == undefined){
    w = today.getWeek();
}
if(y == undefined)
    y = today.getFullYear();

$.post("./", {
    controller: "project",
    action: "sendInTodoLoggin",
    data: projects,
    week: w,
    year: y
}, function(data) {
    try{
        dat = eval('(' + data + ')');
    }catch(err){
        alert("Error: " + data);
        return;
    }

    if(dat == 1){
        setTimeout("end('"+projectId+"')", 1000);
    }else{
        $("#loadImg").hide();
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Which line is reporting the error on?

Comment: That's not jQuery. That's Javascript. jQuery is just a library, and if you don't know the language, it won't make you good (or, obviously, correct) code ;)

Answer (score 3):

stopped reading at line 5:

```
missing ;
```

Comment: I never forget those hours spent looking for an error, and then figuring out I forgot my colon. ARGH!

Comment: I fixed this yesterday, i don't think this was a problem. In the end the php was returning bad data.

Answer (score 2):

This is one reason why I don't like the convention of writing the opening brace '{' to the right of the 'if', 'for', etc., statements. It just makes things confusing and I don't know the reason behind liking this kind of antisymmetry! The braces in:

```
if (...)
{
    if (...)
    {
        if (...)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

is definitely easier to match than:

```
if (...) {
    if (...) {
        if (...) {
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway, as a good rule to solve braces problem, the first thing would be to use a Find-Replace to count the number of opening and closing braces and whether they match or not. If they don't, you can use any good editor (that highlights the matching brackets when you put the cursor over a bracket) and search for '(' and '{' and see whether the matching bracket highlighted is the one you intended or not.

Comment: +1 for the most epic bracketing convention ever. Python makes it even harder to stop using it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, Python is good at this, it would even complain if you use tab characters in one line of a block, and spaces in the next line, so it kind of force you to organize your code :-)

Comment: That's a taste question, not a bible. I preffer the one you hate, it's more comfortable for me. I can see the open and close since the if()

Answer (score 1):

Is your data being returned from the post action not well formed?

Comment: Indeed it was not, the post action fell into a else-statement that would return rubbish.

I did not write the code, i took the project over. I never used JQuery before, it's a bit hard at first time. But now i debug with firebug and use netbeans+xdebug for debugging. Thank you for all the answers.